# Twilio A2P 10DLC Migration

Tags: twilio

We currently use short code sms for our messaging to customers. Is it mandatory that we migrate to A2P or can we stick with the short code method?

Answer (score 2):

For a dedicated shortcode:

1. Messages must have a single sender name
2. Opt-in must be controlled by the owner of the short code and not happen via other brands
3. Other brands must not have access on sending or customizing the messages.

If you cannot meet all three, it is considered a shared shortcode by the carrier and you will need to migrate to 10DLC numbers [for each of your customers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv) or a dedicated TF for each customer [Toll Free number](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045004974-Forbidden-message-categories-for-Toll-Free-SMS-and-MMS-in-the-US-and-Canada) .